# What is `ua.css` and why are some CSS properties expandable in inspector?

Tags: css

I got a problem on Firebug tools. You can see the pic. I drag it.. where is it from? and one more think if i write just some css it's expand a lot.. like

```
h2 {
padding: 20px
}
```

but when i am trying to copy my css style then

```
`h2 {
padding-top: 20px;
padding-right: 20px;
padding-bottom: 20px;
padding-right: 20px
position: 0 0;
}
```

please help me

[image]

Comment: It is correct. Or else you can specify specific padding  like padding-left or whatever your want

Comment: padding: 20px is actually padding on all 4 sides (top, left, right, bottom). Like the "expand" version you've posted

Comment: Please give the question a descriptive title.

Comment: `ua.css`. is a stylesheet for the browser itself. You can see a copy of it [here](https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/26729202/).

Comment: For reference, @JaredFarrish's comment referred to the original question title: ***"I can't fix that what is that"***, which I replaced with a more descriptive one.

Answer (score 2):

They are not bugs, but features, Bapy.

1. `ua.css` stands for ***User Agent CSS*** and is internally used by your browser. You need a [`CSS reset`](http://cssreset.com/what-is-a-css-reset/) to override it.
2. In style inspector, all [`shorthand properties`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Shorthand_properties) can be expanded to see each of the individual properties they stand for.

---

**Additional note:** Over (at least) the past year, Firefox has been a step behind Chrome regarding (web) developer tools. Most of their recent enhancements have been implemented after that functionality was initially featured by Chrome dev tools and they look and feel surprisingly similar in Firefox.
For example, at the moment of this writing, Chrome dev tools currently feature a `cubic-bezier()` viewer which is not available yet in Firefox. I expect one to show up in Firefox dev tools over the following months.

For development purposes only, I recommend using Chrome, at least for the time being.

---

Please note the above note does not mean I don't appreciate the extraordinary effort and the quality of [`MDN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) as a resource, which I highly recommend. It is an incredible aid in web-development and has grown to be a dependable source of information on web standards.

Answer (score -1):

CSS has properties for specifying the padding for each side of an element:

padding-top
padding-right
padding-bottom
padding-left

so you must have to use shorthand css like :

```
h2 {
    padding: 50px 30px 50px 80px;
}
```

or you can specify individually by name like

```
h2
{
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-right: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    padding-left: 80px;
}
```

Hopefully it is useful to you :)

Comment: ... or you can specify each top around to right side, like `h2 { padding: 10px 20px; }`, which will be in effect `padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px`, or `padding: 12px 8px 15px;`, which will be `12px 8px 15px 8px`. The `padding: 10px` is simply a fill procedure for any other property settings that haven't been set yet.

Comment: Yea you right..but some days ago  when i did padding-top: 20px; padding-left: 20px; padding-bottom: 20px; that time firebug arrange the code like padding: 20px 20px 20px; this is short hand property so when i am using short hand property they are not allowed.. why is that..